# Drag to dynamically resize a pair of adjacent layouts on Android

Tags: android, layout, resize

I have a pair of adjacent views in an Android application. I'd like to give the user the ability to drag a widget to change the relative size of the two views within a larger container.  If SlidingDrawer let the user pin the drawer wherever they wanted, that'd likely get me what I want.

My Google 'fu is failing me.  I can't find a single example of this anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: any suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24996248/2624806 !

Answer (score 8):

I ended up putting together a bit of code to create a custom LinearLayout subclass to do what I wanted.

The code is at https://github.com/k9mail/splitview

Comment: Very well, this solutions works as expected, but I need some animation properties that I should implement on this code in order to get what I want. Really thank you.