# Scroll and pull back feature implementation

Tags: android, scrollview, android-custom-view

**Update:**

I am designing an custom view but I am not finding way to start it. There are two child view A(some button), B(Scroll/List View) with Fixed height(initially).

Now there are three requirement:

1. User should allow to drag View-B(like SlideDrawer) in upward direction and
2. then View-A will also be pushed along View-A, up to a certain level.
3. Once limit reached then View-B only should allow to scroll.

Added concept image to get clear understanding.

[image][image]

Any suggestion to implement same !!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by *"how can I scroll complete view up to a level"*.

Comment: it is like scroll complete screen view in vertical up direction and let it go until View-A scrolled 25% of it self, once it is done stop scrolling of complete view and allow bottom Scroll View (B) scrolling.

Comment: you can understand in this way: Lock Vertical Scroll of parent and allow only child scrolling.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. In any case, most of GUI designs are already made, no need to reinvent them. I suggest you check [here](http://android-arsenal.com/).

Comment: @m0skit0 Thanks, I checked link but there are library missing..I am not sure from where can get these..meanwhile I have added concept images, to be clear about requirement.

Comment: Is this similar to Spotify Android app list of songs ?

Comment: I am not able to access this app in my country...so not sure.

Comment: @m0skit0 please have a look again..I have revised question.