# make parent scroll to a certain point and then child scroll inside parent

Tags: javascript, css

#### Edit:

Here is a new fiddle that better illustrates what I'm going for: https://jsfiddle.net/gta4eo3L/3/.

Note how in order to see all the child content you need to scroll twice. Once to make the parent go into full view; then again to scroll the content in the parent. My question is how do I make this happen in a seamless motion? In other words, how do I make the scroll "momentum" from the first scroll carry over to the second one.

#### Original:

[image]

How can I achieve this behaviour seamlessly? The parent height is fixed and I can use `position:sticky` to hold it in place; but combined with the `overflow:scroll` property, the child will scroll inside the parent before the parent reaches the stopping point.

Check out my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xzo1teaw/11/

It's kind of working but does not transition smoothly between the parent scrolling and child scrolling within the parent.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code you can share?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I made a fiddle to demo this: https://jsfiddle.net/xzo1teaw/11/ (also updated my question)

Comment: Where is / what is the stopping point of the parent defined to be?

Comment: @petern0691 in my fiddle, the parent has a fixed height and stops when scrolled fully into view

Comment: Thanks.  But, now looking again at your diagram above, I think that by definition is it not possible to scroll a child element to be outside of its parent element.  This could be done with two independent elements and JS to simulate the effect.

Comment: @petern0691 I am not trying to scroll the child out of the parent. I'm using `overflow:scroll`. Essentially I have 2 scrolling elements. 

1. the page itself scrolls (and that's the parent scrolling until it is in full view)
2. the child scrolling inside the parent. 

I want the page to scroll until it can't and then seamless transition to the child scrolling inside the parent.

Comment: Okay. Note that your diagram shows the child outside the parent.

Comment: @petern0691, I made the outside part a different opacity to illustrate the overflow. Sorry if that is misleading.

Comment: Why do you even want this behavior the first place? Seems highly impractical. It's not been done before, probably for a reason. The only similar solution I've seen is having a horizontal menu at the top decrease on scroll to leave space for content.

Comment: A similar question was closed: [Scroll and pull back feature implementation -closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996248/scroll-and-pull-back-feature-implementation)

Comment: @RickardElimää I don't think it is impractical. If this is possible; it offers a seamless scrolling experience instead of making the user have to scroll the card up then the card content again.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you're thought out UX solution isn't the correct one, hence the problem is not in your question.

Comment: @RickardElimää how can I update the question to be more clear about what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively easy to implement once you understand one important thing
**The Child does not have to be a child of Parent**
+ the fact you can use CSS Grid to place multiple elements in one place
+ z-index to place element above sticky

```css
body {
/*  some space to scroll  */
  height: 500vh;
/*  some space to scroll  */
  padding-top: 50vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "only";
  justify-items: center;
}

.parent {
  grid-area: only;
  background: grey;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
/*  one screen height  */
  height: 90vh;
}

.child {
/*  offset for parent  */
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 200vh;
  grid-area: only;
  background: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%,
    rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%,
    rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%
  );
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
}

body * {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   Container
   <div class="parent">Parent</div>
   <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[kinda works](https://jsbin.com/kavuwiwoxo/1/edit?output)

! elements are siblings not parent-child

disclaimer: hacked + tested on an iphone

```html
<div id="p"></div>
<div id="c">child
</div>
```

```css
#p {
user-select: none;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: calc(100vh - 45px);
border: groove 1em cyan;
border-radius: 2em;
}

#p.scrolled {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}

#c {
margin: 300px 1em 45px;
white-space: pre;
}
```

```js
c.textContent = Array(100).join(c.textContent);

addEventListener('scroll', () =>
  p.className = scrollY > 300
    ? 'scrolled'
    : '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the fiddle below....

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var child = document.getElementById('child');

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    parent.classList.add('overflow-scroll');
    child.classList.add('top-child');
  } else {
    parent.classList.remove('overflow-scroll');
    child.classList.remove('top-child');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.background {
  background: skyblue;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -35px;
  background: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 24px;
  border-top-right-radius: 24px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 32px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 32px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 32px 8px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 98%;
}

.child {
  background: rgb(131, 58, 180);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: -30vh;
}

.parent,
.child {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar,
.child::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30vh;
}

.top-child {
  top: 30vh;
  /*100px minus margin (14px)*/
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  Background
</div>
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  Parent

  <p>
    the parent looks like a card that slides over the background
  </p>

</div>
<div class="child" id="child">
  the child element does not have a defined height and can be very long
  <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget nibh rutrum, porta quam ac, rutrum erat. Donec ultricies, dolor vel iaculis rutrum, nunc tellus pulvinar ante, a malesuada erat sapien at lectus. In quis ligula augue. Aliquam
  auctor nulla nec mattis viverra. Aliquam eget felis velit. Nulla euismod lectus eu sapien aliquam convallis dapibus ut sem. Nullam vestibulum ante non lacinia finibus. Donec lacinia ultricies arcu id sollicitudin. Aliquam a venenatis arcu, et congue
  justo. Etiam vitae augue tortor. Etiam sed nulla dui. Vestibulum elementum euismod eleifend. In eu aliquam mauris. Sed sit amet tempor quam. Mauris in mi lacus. Pellentesque vestibulum vehicula blandit. Phasellus consectetur iaculis libero, maximus
  euismod tortor ultrices nec. Duis eget lacinia quam. Vivamus sit amet tincidunt neque. Maecenas sed mauris dignissim, consequat justo ac, mollis arcu. Etiam aliquet enim at orci dapibus, ac aliquam diam aliquet. Nulla quis magna sit amet ante interdum
  iaculis. Duis pharetra erat sit amet mi interdum pharetra. Maecenas interdum tortor leo, ac vehicula odio consectetur quis. Ut vitae tincidunt quam. Donec purus ipsum, commodo eget rutrum vitae, aliquam molestie diam. Sed rutrum, tortor vel iaculis
  fermentum, urna quam lacinia libero, a pulvinar lacus arcu pharetra ligula. Sed lacus tortor, dictum quis luctus et, eleifend commodo erat. Sed non metus at leo blandit posuere et in nisi. Duis ornare scelerisque ultricies. Ut vestibulum maximus imperdiet.
  Praesent egestas tristique sem. Curabitur est quam, auctor quis auctor a, placerat porttitor nisi. Pellentesque tristique, tellus vitae porttitor consequat, massa diam lacinia est, at rhoncus arcu nulla et lectus. Donec libero nibh, hendrerit at elementum
  sit amet, gravida vel leo. Aenean vitae nibh at massa tempus scelerisque at eu quam. Nulla facilisi. Nulla vel ligula convallis, consectetur magna sit amet, euismod eros. Aenean et ullamcorper diam. Donec ultricies felis eget venenatis viverra. Ut ut
  risus sit amet libero tincidunt volutpat. Cras dui libero, vehicula sollicitudin bibendum et, dictum eu ex. Sed et magna sem. Sed fermentum diam quis sapien posuere consectetur. Integer vulputate ex sed imperdiet faucibus. Etiam at accumsan nisl. Cras
  semper aliquam tortor, vel semper nulla luctus eu. Duis porta urna eget ex luctus, a pellentesque enim pulvinar. Aliquam neque mauris, cursus vel consectetur nec, blandit id diam. Phasellus vel erat erat.
</div>
```

EDIT: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/ts6dqr8o/57/

2nd EDIT: My third version: https://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/ts6dqr8o/86/

Comment: Not quite. I have made this fiddle (inspired by your js portion) to better illustrate what I am going for: https://jsfiddle.net/gta4eo3L/2/. In my fiddle; you need to scroll twice to see all the child content. Once to make the parent reach the end, then once more to scroll the child. How do I make this one seamless motion? Is this possible at all?

Comment: You mean that you'd want to have only one scrollbar with the fiddle you did?

Comment: not necessarily but if that's possible that would be great too. I want the momentum from the first scroll to transfer to the inner scroll (within the parent) once the parent can no longer be scrolled.

Comment: I made some changes on the above. Despite the lagging, is this what you were looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/ts6dqr8o/57/

Comment: Sorry it this was unclear; the child should be clipped by the parent. It cannot go "over" the card.

Comment: The new version: https://jsfiddle.net/iorgu/ts6dqr8o/86/